# JProfiler 7.0.1 reflection causing IllegalAccessException

Tags: jprofiler

I'm using a VMware jar in my Tomcat webapp to gather VM information.  When launching JProfiler from inside IDEA 10.5 everything runs fine until I call into the VMware jar whereupon I get an `IllegalAccessException`.

Is there a way to prevent JProfiler from looking into the jar?  I tried an exclusion filter on `com.vmware.vim25` but that had no effect.

Here's the stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class com.vmware.vim25.ws.XmlGen can not access a member of class java.lang.Object with modifiers "static transient"
    at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:65)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.doSecurityCheck(Field.java:960)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.getFieldAccessor(Field.java:896)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:358)
    at com.vmware.vim25.ws.XmlGen.toXML(XmlGen.java:696)
    at com.vmware.vim25.ws.XmlGen.toXML(XmlGen.java:633)
    at com.vmware.vim25.ws.XmlGen.toXML(XmlGen.java:707)
    at com.vmware.vim25.ws.XmlGen.toXML(XmlGen.java:633)
    at com.vmware.vim25.ws.XmlGen.toXML(XmlGen.java:584)
    at com.vmware.vim25.ws.WSClient.createSoapMessage(WSClient.java:219)
    at com.vmware.vim25.ws.WSClient.invoke(WSClient.java:170)
    at com.vmware.vim25.ws.WSClient.invoke(WSClient.java:124)
    at com.vmware.vim25.ws.VimStub.retrieveProperties(VimStub.java:77)
    at com.vmware.vim25.mo.PropertyCollector.retrieveProperties(PropertyCollector.java:107)
    at com.vmware.vim25.mo.ManagedObject.retrieveObjectProperties(ManagedObject.java:155)
    at com.vmware.vim25.mo.ManagedObject.getCurrentProperty(ManagedObject.java:179)
    at com.vmware.vim25.mo.ManagedObject.getManagedObjects(ManagedObject.java:221)
    at com.vmware.vim25.mo.ManagedObject.getManagedObjects(ManagedObject.java:268)
    at com.vmware.vim25.mo.ManagedObject.getVms(ManagedObject.java:298)
    at com.vmware.vim25.mo.Datastore.getVms(Datastore.java:81)
```

[snip]

Comment: I've not heard much from the JProfiler people so I tried the eval of YourKit.  It works find in the same environment.

Answer (score 1):

The JProfiler people got back to me and suggested trying a pre-release version of 7.1 as they've changed the way the product works in this area.  This new version does indeed solve this problem so I'm now able to move forward.